# Unauthorized: No token provided

Tags: reactjs, express, error-handling, axios

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import "../styles/ProfilePage.css";
import UserStats from "./UserStats";
import NavBar from "./Navbar";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

function ProfilePage() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userToken = Cookies.get('user');
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile', { 
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`} 
    }) 
      .then(response => {
        setUserData(response.data); 
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <NavBar/>
      <div className="Container">
        <UserStats />
        <div className="Username">
          <span>{userData?.username}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="ProfileDetailsBox">
          <div className="ProfileDetails">
            <span>Email: {userData?.email}</span>
            <span>Tasks Completed: {userData?.task_completed}</span>
            <span>Joined on: {userData?.joined_at}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.user;
  
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized: No token provided');
    }
  
    try {
      var decoded = jwt.verify(token, "ZJGX1QL7ri6BGJWj3t");
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`,[decoded.userId], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).send('Error retrieving user data');
        } else if (results.length === 0) {
          res.status(404).send('User not found');
        } else {
          res.send(results[0]);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(401).send('Unauthorized: Invalid token');
    }
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6dRe.png)

I successfully got a reply from the endpoint using Postman, however when I ran my code, I get an error: `Unauthorized: No token provided', status: 401`.

I'm pretty sure that I already generated a cookie using the login endpoint.
What I expected is that I passed a detail of information of userData from the database to the front end component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the token in the headers instead of cookies.  Try the following instead of "req.cookies.user".

```
const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
const token = authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
```